# Automatically Modify Server Response

Tags: firefox, windows-10, fiddler

**Firefox** does a **get** request to the server. It get's **HTML** page in response.
There is a part of this **HTML** response page that needs to be modified.
There is **jQuery** code in the **Head** section of the **HTML**:

```
    <Head>
    ..
        <script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                init(var1, var2, var3, var4);
                });

        </script>

    ..
    </Head>
```

The **goal** is to:

1. **Intercept** original response.
2. Find this **javascript** part in the **response**.
3. **Edit variables 1 and 3** but **leave as they are variables 2 and 4**.
4. Send **response** to **Firefox**.

**Point 1** I do with **Fiddler** that is connected to **Firefox** through proxy settings. Currently I don't know how to do **points 2, 3 and 4** **automatically**.
I've started to use **Fiddler** only recently and the documentation doesn't have examples of how to do it.

Is there easier way to **send/modify requests/responses based on server requests/responses** in **Windows** **automatically** using other programs?

**Thank You for Your help!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can rewrite server response on the fly with Fiddlers `CustomRules` script:

- Open `FiddlerScript` tab: [image: Fiddler window with FiddlerScript tab]
- (alternatively Open `%userprofile%\Documents\Fiddler2\Scripts\CustomRules.js` file in your editor and locate `static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {`.)
- Amend its body - simple string to string replacement:

  ```
  if (oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type","text/html")){
      oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
      oSession.utilReplaceInResponse('find','replace');
      oSession.utilReplaceInResponse('something','anything');
  }
  ```
- Alternatively regexp:

  ```
  if (oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "html")){
      oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
      var oBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oSession.responseBodyBytes);
      var oRegEx = /([a-z]+) and ([a-z]+)/gi;
      oBody = oBody.replace(oRegEx, "$2 swapped $1");
      oSession.utilSetResponseBody(oBody); 
  }
  ```

(This will supposedly not work in cases when response was NOT UTF-8.)

The script file is "live": any change you save in it while Fiddler is running is propagated (it plays sound on file change, or different sound when you break something with corresponding prompt in Fiddler window).

Docs: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse

Btw for dead simple incoming file replacement, you can use AutoResponder:
[image: Fiddler AutoResponder example]

---

Disclosure: I do not know much about this, just happened to be messing with Fiddler today and tried this certain stuff myself just now.  I suppose that there might be more robust approaches and perhaps even more intelligent proxies with incorporated HTML parsers or such which would fit your problem better; dumb string replacements cannot compete with real HTML parser and so on, but this is the first and yet the only solution I know about.

Comment: Thank You @myf I've used "amend it's body" version. I also found that there is html agility pack to parse html that can be used in fiddler but I haven't tried it as to get to use it is kind of tricky. I think the better way will be to use jquery ajax processing in the javascript file as it can divide the response into variables that can be used as input for a request.

Comment: I think intelligent proxy will use neural networks or some other self-learning technics. If it can win in Mario game and others why developers don't include such things into their programs? This will greatly simplify repetetive tasks for users.

Comment: This answer is great, saved my day! BTW, to get the "FiddlerScript" tab, you must first install _Syntax-Highlighting Add-Ons_ from http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/add-ons